# Passing a virtual property value to the Mongoose `pre-save` hook

Tags: mongoose

In my MongoDB/Node backend I am using Mongoose middleware (pre/post hooks) in order to generate notes when certain aspects of the document change. Everything's working as expected -- except for one piece. I need to know the _id of the last person who made a change to the record - so that can be included in the generated note.

Now, if this value could be saved to a property on the document it'd be fairly simple. I would just assign that value to a property like "lastModifiedBy". However, the direction for this project does not allow for this.

So, I'm wondering if I can do this with a virtual property? I'm clear on how to generate a virtual property from data that exists on the document, like so:

```
personSchema.virtual('name.full').get(function () {
  return this.name.first + ' ' + this.name.last;
});
```

But how would this work when the value is not parsed from data already on the document model?

And, to clarify, in my function that updates the record, I DO have access to this value. But how do I pass that value to my triggers file via the `pre-save` hook? That's the question I'm wrestling with. If possible, a basic demonstration of how this would work would be helpful. Or, if there's a different way to accomplish this I'd be open to that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can pass the value to your pre-save hook: use a ES6 symbol, like so:

```
const lastModifiedBy = Symbol.for('lastModifiedBy');

// later
app.getAsync(async (req, res) => {
  const doc = await MyModel.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
  doc[lastModifiedBy] = req.params.staffId;
  // Can now access `this[lastModifiedBy]` in save middleware: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html
  await doc.save();
});
```